# understanding c-'0'

Tags: c

I was trying to test one of the K&R function which uses c-'0'. To understand clearly I wrote a two line code as below. My question is why is it printing "1". And what does the "numeric value" actually mean in this context. Thanks!

```
char c = 'a';
printf("%c",c-'0');
```

Comment: It should be mentioned that this code doesn't make any sense in real applications, nor should it be relied upon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`c - '0'` only has a definite specific value when c is a digit ('0', '1', ..., or '9').

When `c` is `'0'`, `'0' - '0'` is `0` because they are equal
when `c` is `'1'`, `'1' - '0'` is `1` because `'1'` immediately follows `'0'` in any character set any C implementation choses to use.
The same for `'2'` and the other digits: `'9' - '0'` has a value of `9`.

And you really shouldn't print a value with the `"%c"` format specifier.

Answer (score 7):

The numerical value is the ASCII value of the character.

`'a'` is 97, `'0'` is 48. 97-48=49.

49, in turn, is the value of `'1'`, so that's what is printed.

Comment: So essentially, when (ASCII for 5 is 53 and for 3 is 51 so number is 53 - 51 : 2)

`printf("ASCII for %c is %d so number is %d - %d : %d\n", '5', '5', '5', '3', '5'-'3');`

Comment: The part about "number is 53 - 51 : 2" I don't understand. The said conversion makes only sense for `'0'`, because that is the "neutral element of the addition in ASCII digits": I as well can convert the `'5'` to `53` with `'5' - '3' + 3`, but that is more complicated than just `'5' - '0'`.

Comment: I meant that '5' - '0' = 5 because ASCII values are 53 - 48, which = 5. Because in ASCII (asserting it's true in any encoding), digits have sequential codes, even if they don't start at 0.
Would this be correct?

Comment: So basically '5' - '0' works to get the value of 5 because of the ASCII encoding values?

Comment: @jslvtr Because they are 5 places apart in the ASCII table: '012345', starting with value 48. If the `0` was at te end, such as on telephone dialers, this technique wouldn't work.

Answer (score 6):

Characters in C are nothing more than just an integer value. Their value is defined according to a [character encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding). The [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)  encoding is very well-known and the one that applies to the question posted by the OP. Therefore '0' equals 48 and 'a' equals 97. By subtracting them you are just getting the difference between those characters in the ASCII table.

In this example (equivalent to yours):

```
printf("%c",'a'-'0');
```

you get `1` since 97-48 = 49 which corresponds to ASCII character '1'.

If instead you were using (note the "%d" instead of "%c"):

```
printf("%d",'a'-'0');
```

Then this would print only the difference (49 in this case), and not the ASCII character associated to the difference.

Comment: it is not necessarily ASCII, just some encoding

Comment: @JensGustedt I was somehow simplifying it a bit, since in the context of the OP's question, I do not think another encoding is being used. Anyway, I will update the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

The behavior of your code is implementation dependent. It relies on the encoding of characters.

On my Linux machine, the `a` character is encoded in [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii) (and in UTF8) as the single byte `97` (decimal), i.e. `0x61`. Likewise the `0` character is encoded as `48` i.e. `0x30`.  The difference `'a' - '0'` is `97 - 48` that is `49` which happens to be the encoding of character `1`

On some ancient [EBCDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) machine (e.g. old IBM mainframes, or new ones running in some compatibility mode or operating system) encoding is different.

With [UTF8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF8) (now very often used) many more characters exist (e.g. the C cedilla `ç` for French spelling), and they usually are encoded in more than one byte!

Answer (score 2):

c - '0' will subtract the character code of '0'(48) from c. If c represents a digit this will result in the numeric value corresponding to c(3 for the char '3' for instance).

Still in order to get this numeric value you should use the format specifier %d in printf instead of %c.

It does not make much sense to subtract '0' from 'a' but maybe it will have some application for a particular task.

Answer (score 1):

Lets explain this little more by using integers instead of characters.

```
char c = 97;
printf("%d", c - 48);
```

This will of course print 49, but as we translate this to character with the ASCII table we get 1.

```
char c = 97;
printf("%c", c-48);
```

This code now prints 1 because we use char datatype when we print and it translates the 49 value into the ASCII equivalent number 1.

To prove this we can try something like this.

```
char a = 'a';
char b = 97;
if((a == b) && ((a-'0') == (b-48))) { 
      printf("%s", "true");
}
```

First we see if a and b are equivalent and then we see if a-'0' is equivalent with b-48. Since both are true we print true.

Answer (score 0):

Character within single quote, like '0', is a character constant. It is a number constant depending on the machine's character set. In ASCII character set, 'a' is equivalent to 97 and '0' is 48.

97-48 = 49, which is equivalent to '1' in ASCII character set. In the end, it will print '1' in %c format.